# FBO not rendering or changing anything

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, fbo

Recently, I am making a 3D game. I want to do special post processing effects, like pixelization. I used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9fal.png) to load do everything with FBOS, but it's kindof weird...

In some code for the initialization of the FBO, it stops, and errors out with the error code `1280`, which aparently means `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, and it all started when I put in this code in my `FBO` class:

```
GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderTex, 0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

It errors out, then closes (by if statement). If I don't close it, it renders black, like this:

[image]

If I change `glFramebufferTexture2D` to `glFramebufferTexture`, it just turns black and no error outputs.

I seriously have no idea how.

maybe it's by the classes that's causing this, so here they are:

Main Class:

```
package me.pale.main;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

import me.pale.model.Voxel;
import me.pale.postprocess.FBO;
import me.pale.postprocess.PostProcessQuad;
import me.pale.shader.Shader;

public class BlockGame {
    
    float fac = 16;
    
    float t = 16;
    
    Texture testtex;
    
    float rot;
    
    Shader shader;
    Shader postprocess;
    
    PostProcessQuad ppq = new PostProcessQuad();
    
    Voxel test = new Voxel();
    
    public void window(String name, int width, int height) throws LWJGLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.create();
        
        FBO fbo = new FBO();
        
        shader = new Shader("res/fragment.glsl", "res/vertex.glsl");
        postprocess = new Shader("res/ppfrag.glsl", "res/ppvert.glsl");
        
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GLU.gluPerspective(90.0f, 1.333f, 0.1f, 650.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthMask(true);
        
        GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac);
        
        GL11.glTranslated(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        
        
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            
            if (fac < 0) {
                
                fac = 0;
                t = 0;
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
                
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac -= 0.025f);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "t"), t -= 0.025f);
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
                
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac += 0.025f);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "t"), t += 0.025f);
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_R)) {
                
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), 16);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "t"), 16);
                
            }
            
            rot += 0.05f;
            
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
            GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
            //GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, testtex.getTextureID());
            
            
            // shader.start();
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(-4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glBindTexture(0, fbo.getRenderTex());
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
            GL11.glEnd();
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            
            fbo.bindFBOS();
            postprocess.start();
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(-4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            ppq.draw();
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            fbo.unbind();
            
            postprocess.halt();
            
            shader.start();
            
            GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "f"), rot/10);
            
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            
                GL11.glRotatef(rot, 1, 1, 1);
            
                test.draw();
                
            
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            
            shader.halt();
            // shader.halt();
            
            Display.update();
            
        }
        
        fbo.wash();
        postprocess.wash();
        shader.wash();
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        BlockGame bg = new BlockGame();
        bg.window("Game", 640, 480);
        
    }
    
}
```

FBO Class:

```
package me.pale.postprocess;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL32;

public class FBO {
    
    int defaultFBO;
    int defaultTEX;
    int defaultDEPTH;
    
    public FBO() {
        
        init();
        
    }

    public int createFBO() {
        
        int fbo = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        // GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
        GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        
        return fbo;
        
    }
    
    public int createRenderTexture() {
        
        int renderTex = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, 640, 480, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderTex, 0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        
        int drawBuffer = GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
        
        GL20.glDrawBuffers(drawBuffer);
        
        if (GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            
            System.out.println("ERR: error occurred making FBO " + GL11.glGetError());
            System.exit(-1);
            
        }
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        
        return renderTex;
        
    }
    
    public void bind(int fbo) {
        
        // GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
        
    }
    
    public void unbind() {
        
        // GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        
    }
    
    public void render() {
        
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
        
    }
    
    private int createDepthBuffer() {
        
        int depthRenderBuffer = GL30.glGenRenderbuffers();
        GL30.glBindRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
        GL30.glRenderbufferStorage(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 640, 480);
        GL30.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
        
        return depthRenderBuffer;
        
    }
    
    public void bindFBOS() {
        
        bind(defaultFBO);
        
    }
    
    public void init() {
        
        defaultFBO = createFBO();
        defaultTEX = createRenderTexture();
        defaultDEPTH = createDepthBuffer();
        unbind();
        
    }
    
    public void wash() {
        
        GL30.glDeleteFramebuffers(defaultFBO);
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(defaultTEX);
        
    }

    public int getRenderTex() {
        return defaultTEX;
    }

    public int getFbo() {
        return defaultFBO;
    }
}
```

Be in mind that I used [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) link and ThinMatrix's water tutorial, episode 2.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Ok, so I've looked at the wiki for glframebuffertexture2D, and updated the parameters, but now its all black

Answer (score 1):

Here, you used the wrong order of parameters:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(
    GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
    GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
    renderTex, 
    0, 
    GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

As specified by the [documentation](http://docs.gl/gl3/glFramebufferTexture), it should have been:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(
    GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
    GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
    GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
    renderTex, 
    0);
```

Also in Java, I think you can use something like this:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
```

which allows you to write

```
public void render() {
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    
}
```

See! No need to write `GL11` or `GL30`.